# How to reduce space before the equal sign and right-align string before?

Tags: equations, align

I make an equation in LaTeX, but I find there is too much whitespace before `=` and the part before the equal sign  isn't right-aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
    SI_{c}&=A\\
    \mathrm{pH}_s&=B\\
    \mathrm{p}K_{2}&=C\\
    \mathrm{p}K_{s}&=D\\
    \mathrm{p}f_{m}&=E\\
    A&=F\\
    E&=G
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest to consider having the brace to the right instead of to the left. You can do as in Micos answer, but with `\left\{` changed into `\left.` and `\right.` changed into `\right\}`, (Since you have numbers to the right)

Comment: @mickep Having the brace to the right will make those equations seem not so tidy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you employ an `aligned` environment inside the `cases` environment. In fact, since you're not really making use of the machinery of the `cases` environment, I would further like to suggest that you replace `\begin{cases}` and `\end{cases}` with `\left\{` and `\right.`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    SI_{c}&=A\\
    \mathrm{pH}_s&=B\\
    \mathrm{p}K_{2}&=C\\
    \mathrm{p}K_{s}&=D\\
    \mathrm{p}f_{m}&=E\\
    A&=F\\
    E&=G
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello. May you tell me why you felt I didn't make use of the machinery of the `cases` envirnment?

Comment: @Y.zeng - The `cases` environment consists of two columns, with the material in the first column stating results and the material in the second column stating the conditions under which the results in the first column apply. That's not what you're doing.

Comment: Okay. I know now. Thanks a lot.